# How to use websocket in Netty to make corresponding processing according to the routing address?

Tags: java, kotlin, netty

I have two routing addresses, and I want to handle these two routings separately, but I haven't found an entry point.

For example, there are two routing paths:

```
ws://192.168.101.7:8088/article/upload
ws://192.168.101.7:8088/user/upload
```

server code:

```kotlin
try {
    val serverBootstrap = ServerBootstrap()
    serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel::class.java)
        .childHandler(articleUploadHandler)
        .childHandler(hotHubUploadChannelHandler)
    val channel = serverBootstrap.bind(8088).sync().channel()
    println("websocket服务已启动")
    channel.closeFuture().sync()
}finally {
    bossGroup.shutdownGracefully()
    workerGroup.shutdownGracefully()
}
```

ChildHandler

```kotlin
class ArticleUploadChannelHandler : ChannelInitializer<Channel>() {

    override fun initChannel(ch: Channel?) {
        ch!!.pipeline().addLast(
            HttpServerCodec(),
            HttpObjectAggregator(65536),
            WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/article/upload"),
            MessageHandler(articleItemService),
        )
    }
}
```

Based on my guesses, I tried two options:

1. Add two `childHandler`, but the test failed, only one `childHandler` works.
2. Let `MessageHandler` or `initChannel` get the routing path, but I don't know how.

How should it be solved?